# PHP: Array as var_export/include vs. (un)serialize vs. json_(en|de)code

Tags: php, arrays

I have to transfer a big array from one server to another using a file. It's a multidimensional, but quite simple array. Now I'm searching for the most efficient way, to get this file into my application on the second server. So this question is about the file->array part, not the array->file part on the first server.

Of course I did some benchmarks on the 3 alternatives that seemed most promising. My complete benchmark data:

time:

- include: 0.338...
- unserialize: 0.180...
- **json_decode: 0.134...**

peak memory usage:

- include: 384374.64
- **unserialize: 201377.28**
- json_decode: 219528.08

file size:

- include: 3135 kB
- unserialize: 3142 kB
- **json_decode: 1838 kB**

I think json_decode is the way to go, because peak memory usage is my smallest concern and even there json is quite good. But the speed and file size of json just rocks. I woul have never thought it to be that fast.

Any objections or other suggestions?

Comment: You seem to have found the solution yourself. Now you just need to follow through (and use JSON). :)

Comment: +1 - It's great that you did all that work before coming here and asking your question.  Most wouldn't have gone to the effort.

Comment: Surely the include method should be fastest as it's already php code? Am I missing something?

Comment: @aland: I don't know how was the benchmark done, but I would guess

Comment: The include method may be a bit slower than the other methods because PHP has to parse source code instead of highly parseable text. However, if you are using a bytecode cache like APC it should be the fastest way to load the data since it only has to be parsed once and then all subsequent requests will just use the cached byte code.

Comment: Tested with APC on PHP 5.3, var_export include is much faster (3.8ms in my use-case) than json_decode() (15.7ms). In fact, even without APC the include is faster (11.8ms). So, YMMV :)

Comment: Since PHP 7 it's a matter of seconds to enable opcache which will likely throw the original findings totally in favor of var_export+include. Same thing as APC which was already mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kudos to Jan for 
1) actually trying out different methods
2) sharing the results

Some time ago, I was working on an AI system whwew the knowledgebase was stored in a large array. I found it was an order of magnitude faster to rebuild the entire array from database records (local mysql, approx 30,000 rows) rather than unserialize the array from a file.

(This also meant that I was later able to amend the code to only selectively load the relevant parts of the knowledge tree which speeded it up even more).

HTH

C.

Answer (score 0):

I Did similar benchmark. Conclusion:

- var_dump / include is off discussion. Rumost telling that this is the fastest are not true. And this is security suicide.
- serialize could be the best. But, becouse I need to force JSON for part of interchanges, benefits on serialize is relative small, I will use JSON as only format for interchange.

PHP 7.4.30 (3 years old server)

```
root@iphead-4ever:/var/www/V2api/concepts# php test_serialize.php
--------------------
empty cycle with static assignments x 1000000 took 14.46 ms
--------------------
json_encode x 1000000 took 351.44 ms
json_decode x 1000000 took 1363.33 ms
json_decode with file reads x 1000000 took 8001.36 ms
--------------------
serialize x 1000000 took 266.13 ms
unserialize x 1000000 took 535.9 ms
unserialize with file reads x 1000000 took 7276.53 ms
--------------------
var_export x 1000000 took 2035.29 ms
iclude x 1000000 took 18579.56 ms
```

PHP 8.2.4 (Fast video preprocessor optimized machine)

```
--------------------
empty cycle with static assignments x 1000000 took 2.12 ms
--------------------
json_encode x 1000000 took 132.67 ms
json_decode x 1000000 took 566.32 ms
json_decode with file reads x 1000000 took 2507.09 ms
--------------------
serialize x 1000000 took 126.55 ms
unserialize x 1000000 took 244.77 ms
unserialize with file reads x 1000000 took 2115.02 ms
--------------------
var_export x 1000000 took 610.44 ms
iclude x 1000000 took 3896.73 ms
```

PHP 8.2.5 (New server)

```
--------------------
empty cycle with static assignments x 1000000 took 5.07 ms
--------------------
json_encode x 1000000 took 163.48 ms
json_decode x 1000000 took 609.36 ms
json_decode with file reads x 1000000 took 2777.67 ms
--------------------
serialize x 1000000 took 125.08 ms
unserialize x 1000000 took 290.1 ms
unserialize with file reads x 1000000 took 2433.13 ms
--------------------
var_export x 1000000 took 717.83 ms
iclude x 1000000 took 4470.75 ms
```